# How to identify long value using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to check whether the values received in a file upload column has `exponential` or long values.

For example, if value is `5.02E+13` instead of numeric value - 50100434157080 then need to restrict it with a message saying format is incorrect.

For this I pass the upload content from frontend to backend in a temporary table and then get it checked if passed value has exponential value or numeric value.

Tried using T-SQL function `isnumeric()` but it didn't give me expected result. Any other function available?

Comment: What is the column's data type? What database?

Comment: Column is for Account Number a varchar column. When account numbers are maintained in excel sometimes they are read in different format (ex.expontential form) in the dataTable. Hence I need to give validation and restrict such entries.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention using `isnumeric` I assume you are using SQL Server, in which case you can try `try_cast`, for example

```
select case when Try_Cast(Column as bigint) is null then 'not integer' else 'integer' end
from table
```

You could also use `like`

```
select case when Column like '%e%' then 'exponent' else 'number' end
from table
```

Comment: What if 'e' is not present in the value?

Comment: @JenK The assumption from the sample data is it will, since without `e` it won't have an exponent.